# How to enter/type Emoji in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Latest versions of IntelliJ supports emoji (in code or comments). Is there a shortcut to use them?

Tried to search in google the answer but did not find.

Comment: have you tried [win]+[.] combination? use the [>.] button not the one in the keypad area. in Win10 this is the shortcut for emojies.

Comment: Thanks, that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[win]+[.] combination, use the [>.] button not the one in the keypad area.